# Facebook accessibility best practice for image alt text

Tags: image, facebook, accessibility

I was researching alternative text for Facebook images and found out they do this automatically with AI with no override capability.

I'm assuming that when people also add text descriptions in the main post this causes a problem with double up on screen readers. What is best practice for accessibility on the poster's part or Facebook's part?

Answer (score 1):

When you click on an image in facebook to enlarge it, there's an `Options` pop-up menu at the bottom right of the image, which contains the option "change alt text". In the following dialog, you can choose to overwrite the automatically generated alt text.